# Perpendicular bisectors of parts of chords

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image]
$AB$ and $AC$ are two chords of a circle. Let points $D$ and $E$ lie on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively such that $AD$ = $AE$. The perpendicular bisector of $BD$ intersects the circle at points $F$ and $P$, such that $F$ lies on the opposite side of $AB$. Similarly, the perpendicular bisector of $CE$ intersects the circle at points $G$ and $Q$ such that $G$ lies on the opposite side of $AC$. Let $FP$ $\cap$ $GQ = T$, How to prove that $TF = TG$, or is that true?

Comment: Please provide more context to the question, thus showing and sharing the effort of solving the problem, it is the way it works! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question In such cases, a picture would be nice. Which are your attempts...?

Comment: The statement $TF$ is equal to $TG$ is true. If you draw a diagram to scale using Geogebra, you can see that yourself. If you have already done that, please post it with your problem statement to attract the attention of the members of MSE community.

Comment: actually, I stumbled on this while solving a problem, I tried but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @SayemRahman Oh wait, you meant $D$ and $E$ are on the segments $AB$ and $AC$? In my solution, I thought you meant on the arcs $AB$ and $AC$.

Comment: @AnCar, um yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Bisectors]

Our aim here is to use certain properties of a special case of the given scenario to find a synthetic proof of the statement $TP=TG$. This special case, of which $AE=AD=0$, is shown in red. In this instance, the perpendicular bisectors of both chords, i.e. $P_0Q_0$ and $G_0H_0$, passes through the centre $O$ of the circle, the radius of which is $R$.  Let $AB=b$ and $AC=c$. Then, we have,
$$AM_0=M_0B=\dfrac{b}{2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad AN_0=N_0C=\dfrac{c}{2}.$$

For brevity, for the scenario described in OP’s problem statement, we assume $AE=AD=a$. Therefore, we shall write,
$$DB=b-a\quad\rightarrow\quad DM=MB=\dfrac{b-a}{2}\qquad\text{and}$$
$$EC=c-a\quad\rightarrow\quad EN=NC=\dfrac{c-a}{2}.\qquad\qquad$$

Now, we can determine the lengths of $MM_0$ and $NN_0$ as shown below.
$$MM_0=M_0B-MB=\dfrac{b}{2}-\dfrac{b-a}{2}=\dfrac{a}{2}\tag{1}$$
$$NN_0=N_0C-NC=\dfrac{c}{2}-\dfrac{c-a}{2}=\dfrac{a}{2}\quad\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it is obvious that $MM_0=NN_0$.
To finish the proof, we draw the two radii $OP$ and $OG$, and join $O$ to $T$. Let $OT=d$. Furthermore, we drop two perpendiculars from $O$ to $GH$ and $PQ$, so that we have,
$$OU= MM_0=\dfrac{a}{2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad  OV= NN_0=\dfrac{a}{2}.$$

Now use the two right angled triangles $OVP$ and $TVO$ to calculate the length of $TP$.
$$TP= \sqrt{R^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}+\sqrt{d^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}$$

Finally, by considering the two right angled triangles $GUO$ and $OUT$, length of $TG$ can be expressed as,
$$TG= \sqrt{R^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}+\sqrt{d^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}.$$

Comment: If call $R = M_0 O\cap TG$ and $S = N_0 O\cap TP$, then it is nice to alternatively proceed using congurences.  

**1.** By AAS criterion $\triangle OVS \cong \triangle OUR$. Thus $UR \cong VS$

**2.**  Hence $ORVS$ is a rhombus. Which implies that $RT \cong ST$

**3.**  HL criterion gives $\triangle OGU \cong \triangle OPV$, hence $GU \cong PV$.

Composing **1.**, **2.**, and **3.** yields the thesis.

Comment: @dfnu Thanks for suggesting an alternative method to prove the second part of our solution. We like it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a nice solution, but I subscribe to the idea that whenever I am not smart enough to see an elementary geometry solution, I try analytic geometry. I am sure there must be a clever elementary geometry solution. Anyway, here goes.

By choosing the coordinate system nicely, we can assume that the circle is the unit circle and that $A$ has coordinates $A(1,0)$. Now we can choose numbers $0\leq \phi,\alpha,\beta \leq \pi$ with $\phi\leq \min{\alpha,\beta}$ such that the points $B,C,D,E$ have coordinates $D(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ , $E(\cos\phi,-\sin\phi)$, $B(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ and $C(\cos\beta,-\sin\beta)$. We will take $T$ to have coordinates $T(x,y)$.

Now, let $M\big(\frac{\cos\phi+\cos\alpha}{2},\frac{\sin\phi+\sin\alpha}{2}\big)$ be the midpoint of the segment $BD$ and, similarly, let $N\big(\frac{\cos\phi+\cos\beta}{2},-\frac{\sin\phi+\sin\beta}{2}\big)$ be the midpoint of the segment $CE$.

We will denote by $m_{XY}$ the slope of a line passing through the points $X$ and $Y$. Since $TM\perp BD$, $m_{TM}\cdot m_{BD}=-1$. This translates to
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin\phi-\sin\alpha}{\cos\phi-\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{y-\frac{\sin\phi+\sin\alpha}{2}}{x-\frac{\cos\phi+\cos\alpha}{2}}=-1. 
\end{equation}

Simplifying, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
(\sin\phi-\sin\alpha)y=-(\cos\phi-\cos\alpha)x. \quad (*)
\end{equation}

By doing the same based on the fact that $NT\perp CE$ and simplifying again, we arrive at the equation

\begin{equation}
(\sin\phi-\sin\beta)y=(\cos\phi-\cos\beta)x. \quad (**)
\end{equation}

Clearly, $y=0$ if and only if $x=0$ in view of any of $(*)$ or $(**)$.

Let us therefore assume that $x\neq 0$ (and therefore $y\neq 0$). We can now write the ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ in two different ways based on $(*)$ and $(**)$.

This leads to the equation

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\sin\phi-\sin\alpha}{\cos\phi-\cos\alpha}=\frac{\sin\phi-\sin\beta}{\cos\phi-\cos\beta}. \quad (***)
\end{equation}

Now we can use some known trigonometric identities, namely
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sin u-\sin v &= 2 \sin\frac{u-v}{2} \cos\frac{u+v}{2} \\
\cos u-\cos v &= -2 \cos \frac{u-v}{2} \cos\frac{u+v}{2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Utilizing these, we can reduce $(***)$ to $\tan\frac{\alpha-\phi}{2}=\tan\frac{\phi-\beta}{2}$, which implies that there exists some integer $k$ such that $\frac{\alpha-\phi}{2}=\frac{\phi-\beta}{2}+k\pi$, or $\alpha+\beta-2\phi=2k\pi$. In view of how we set the domains for $\phi,\alpha,\beta$, this can only occur when $\alpha=\beta=\pi$ and $\phi=0$. In this degenerate case, $T$ is obviously the center of the circle.

Otherwise, we reach a contradiction to the assumption that $x$ or $y$ are not $0$.

In conclusion, $T$ always has coordinates $(0,0)$ and is therefore the center of the circle. The desired conclusion now follows trivially since $F$ and $G$ are points on the circle.